# What type of silkscreen ink is used in PCB manufacturing?

Tags: pcb, manufacturing

Let's say I'm looking to start my own PCB manufacturing company* and I have everything figured out except how to silkscreen the boards.

- Where do I get silkscreen ink from?
- Is there a special type of ink specifically for PCBs?
- What type of properties would I be looking for in a good silkscreen ink?
- Can the inks be tinted to create any color I wish?

Of course, I've Googled, but many results deal with silkscreen printing for fabrics and I'm not sure how much of that info applies to PCB manufacturing. 
Thanks.  
*I'm not. :D

Comment: There is a LinkedIn group for 'Electronics Manufacturing', and I think you might find your answer there. BTW, as I understand (a little) of this industry, the answer to some of these questions are treated like trade-secrets.

Comment: The main property of importance particular to "silk screen" printing of PCBs is that PCB cleaning solvents should not remove the markings, and soldering temperatures should not damage the colors. If I was doing this, I'd go with UV polymerization (curing) if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try 'Epoxy Ink PCB Screen Printing' in your favorite search engine.

Here's one source, and the ink description gives away the desirable properties regarding substrate supported, adhesion qualities, curing process and immunity to acid/alkali treatment.

[Du-Pont PCB silkscreen inks](http://www2.dupont.com/MCM/en_US/tech_info/products/printed_electronics.html#pwb)

[Nazdar](http://www.nazdar.com/screen_printing_prod.asp?categoryID=15&sectionID=174&attrCatID=8&attrID=37)

[Another co. I had never heard about](http://opcompany.com/opco3.html)

PS: No personal experience with those. For low volume usage, and DIY silk-screen, I believe people have used inks used for ceramic painting, which need to be cured at high temperature.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a link to some Sun calls them [notation ink](http://www.sunchemical.com/products/printed-circuit-products/products/notation-inks)

Comment: thanks for the tip on 'notation ink'. Never heard it called that before.

Comment: Link is broken.